# How to use :finders and :scoped with Friendly_ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I'm trying to use :finders in conjunction with :scoped, but I'm having trouble with the syntax

My model used to look like this, but then i wasn't able to have two different articles each with their own page 1:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :page_number, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

I can't figure out syntactically how to use :scoped and :finders together. I thought it would be:

```
extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :page_number, :use => :finders, :use => :scoped, :scope => :article
end
```

Is this possible? I know that I can always add friendly.find in my controller, but that doesn't seem ideal.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the following works:

```
friendly_id :page_number, use: [:scoped, :finders], :scope => :article
```